# Compose LazyColumn list item onclick crashes the app

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

My ViewModel

```
package com.example.workspace.viewmodels

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.workspace.ui.screens.FunnelListItem
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class FunnelScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(

) : ViewModel() {
    val ITEM_AREA = 0
    val ITEM_HQ = 1
    val ITEM_PATCH = 2
    val ITEM_CUSTOMER = 3

    val screenTitles = listOf(
        "Select Area",
        "Select HQ",
        "Select Patch",
        "Select Customer"
    )

    val startingPoint = ITEM_AREA
   




    fun getAreas() = mutableListOf(
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_AREA, 1, "Coimbatore BM"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_AREA, 2, "Madurai BM"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_AREA, 3, "Trichy BM"),
        )

    fun getHQs() = mutableListOf(
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_HQ, 1, "Madurai 01"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_HQ, 2, "Madurai 02"),
        )

    fun getPatches() = mutableListOf(
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_PATCH, 1, "Madurai"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_PATCH, 2, "Theni"),
        )

    fun getCustomers() = mutableListOf(
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_CUSTOMER, 1, "Saravanan"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_CUSTOMER, 2, "Pandian"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_CUSTOMER, 3, "Anbu"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_CUSTOMER, 4, "Anbu"),
        FunnelListItem(ITEM_CUSTOMER, 5, "Anbu")
    )  
}
```

My Screen composable

```
package com.example.workspace.ui.screens

import androidx.activity.compose.BackHandler
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableIntStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import com.example.workspace.ui.components.SimpleTopAppBar
import com.example.workspace.ui.navigation.Screen
import com.example.workspace.viewmodels.FunnelScreenViewModel


@Composable
fun FunnelScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    funnelScreenViewModel: FunnelScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){
    val startingPoint = funnelScreenViewModel.startingPoint
    var currentItemType by rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(funnelScreenViewModel.startingPoint)
    }

    val listItems = when(currentItemType) {
        funnelScreenViewModel.ITEM_AREA -> funnelScreenViewModel.getAreas()
        funnelScreenViewModel.ITEM_HQ -> funnelScreenViewModel.getHQs()
        funnelScreenViewModel.ITEM_PATCH -> funnelScreenViewModel.getPatches()
        else -> funnelScreenViewModel.getCustomers()
    }

    fun handleBack() {
        if (currentItemType == 0) {
            navHostController.popBackStack()
        } else {
            currentItemType--
        }
    }
    BackHandler {
        handleBack()
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            SimpleTopAppBar(title = funnelScreenViewModel.screenTitles[currentItemType]) {
               handleBack()

            }
        }
    ) {
        paddingValues -> FunnelScreenContent(Modifier.padding(paddingValues), listItems, onItemClicked = {
           if (currentItemType < 3) {
               currentItemType++
           } else {
               navHostController.navigate(Screen.CallDetailsScreen.route)
           }
    })
    }

}

@Composable
fun FunnelScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier,
    listItems: List<FunnelListItem>,
    onItemClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
        items(listItems) {
            listItem -> Text(
            text = listItem.name,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        onItemClicked()
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}

data class FunnelListItem(
    val itemType: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

Crash happens when an item is clicked and error is

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.seluriapharma.workspace, PID: 31984
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2, size 2
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.checkIndexBounds(IntervalList.kt:183)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.get(IntervalList.kt:166)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutIntervalContent.getKey(LazyLayoutIntervalContent.kt:86)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImpl.getKey(LazyListItemProvider.kt:85)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure(LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.kt:46)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasureKt.createItemsAfterList(LazyListMeasure.kt:418)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-50ZNEM8(LazyListMeasure.kt:278)

When i replace LazyColumn with regular Column, it works fine. No crashes

```
@Composable
fun FunnelScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier,
    currentItemType: Int,
    funnelScreenViewModel: FunnelScreenViewModel,
    onItemClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    val listItems = when(currentItemType) {
        funnelScreenViewModel.ITEM_AREA -> funnelScreenViewModel.getAreas()
        funnelScreenViewModel.ITEM_HQ -> funnelScreenViewModel.getHQs()
        funnelScreenViewModel.ITEM_PATCH -> funnelScreenViewModel.getPatches()
        else -> funnelScreenViewModel.getCustomers()
    }
    /*LazyColumn(modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
        items(listItems) {
            listItem -> Text(
            text = listItem.name,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        onItemClicked()
                    }
            )
        }
    }*/

    Column(modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        listItems.forEach {
           item -> Text(
                text = item.name,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        onItemClicked()
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My Dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha10")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.4")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")

    val ktorVersion = "1.6.3"
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.0")

    // ObjectBox dependencies
    implementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-android:3.7.0")

    // Dagger hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

Comment: Does it crash on the first click or randomly? What happens if your second list `HQs` is not smaller than the first list `Areas`?

Comment: Crashes. And it happens only with LazyColumn. not with Column

Comment: @JanItor when the count of Areas is 3 and that of HQs is 2, onclick of area item crashes

Comment: @IndraKumarS what version of the compose foundation library are you using ? alpha08 has this issue

Comment: @Hector Added all the dependencies to the question

Comment: @IndraKumarS nice, try running this command '''.\gradlew app:dependencies'''  it will list all dependencies being used by your app. if alpha08 is listed that needs omitting some how

Comment: You are right ! Its there!

Comment: @Hector and how can we fix it? eventually? also have alpha08 in here

Comment: We cannot resolve this issue, we need Google to fix it