# IndexOutOfBoundsException for LazyPagingItems.refresh() with Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3, compose-multiplatform

```
class PagingSource(
    private val repository: InboxRepository,
    private val receiverId: String
) : PagingSource<Int, Item>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Item>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Item> {
        return try {
            val page = params.key ?: 1
            val result = repository.inbox(receiverId, page, 20)

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = result.getOrThrow().messages,
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page.minus(1),
                nextKey = if (result.getOrThrow().messages.isNotEmpty()) page + 1 else null
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I get my items in my ViewModel

private fun getInboxList() {

```
class ItemsVM : ViewModel() {

init {
        getInboxList()
    }

private fun getInboxList() {
        val pagingConfig = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 20,
            prefetchDistance = 5,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        )

        val messageItem = Pager(
            config = pagingConfig,
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                InboxPagingSource(inboxRepository, receiverId)
            }
        ).flow
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)

        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                messages = messageItem
            )
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting an error below when I try to cal

`Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 39, Size: 20`

I have tried looking here [Why is android compose LazyColumn now failing with indexoutofbounds exception following upgrade from alpha07 to alpha08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77357872/why-is-android-compose-lazycolumn-now-failing-with-indexoutofbounds-exception-fo/77358014#77358014) but it doesn't give me any answers.